# can i use L298N H bridge with 12v 7AH battery?

Tags: l298n

guys i am working on a rare project so i just need to ask some questions

I have a L298N H bridge motor driver, a Aduino uno board, 12v dc 4000rpm 2ampere motor and a 12v 7ah battery
I just want to ask can i use 12v 7ah battery with my L298N H bridge motor driver
please answer this project is very important to me
please help

Comment: Probably, as long as the specifications of the motor and the H-bridge are met. Remember a fully charged 12V battery delvers about 12.7-12.8 Volts. Don’t discharge it beyond 50% (3.5Ah).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, though at 2A you're at the top end of the L298N current limit. Expect excessive heating. You will have to manage your thermal environment appropriately.

You should consider a more capable driver with more current headroom and less heat problems. (Note: the L298N is a very old chip and uses old technology. It's not a good choice for modern drive systems and a more appropriate device should be investigated, for example the MC33931 as the first hit on google).